# EntityFramework multiple context use single shared table in database

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

is there any way to share a table in database with multiple context of EF ?
I want to define many models (code first) and bind theme to a single table in a database like this:

```
 public class Context1 : DbContext
{
    [Table("Post")]
    public DbSet<Post1> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Context2 : DbContext
{
    [Table("Post")]
    public DbSet<Post2> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Context3 : DbContext
{
    [Table("Post")]
    public DbSet<Post3> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

all post models are inherited from a basePost for example.

Comment: What happened when you use above way ?

Comment: I think this would work if you disabled database initialization for 2 of the contexts (or all 3 if you create the table yourself). But there would be no way to tell the records in the table apart from each other, so each DbSet would pull the same data. If you want each type of post to behave like its own dataset, the table would need a discriminator column in your table.

Comment: @Sampath it is failed on initialization and said table already exist